# How can I understand the effect of the Sonderweg on the Revolution of 1848?

Tags: 19th-century, germany, revolution, german-unification

I'm trying to understand the effect that the [German 'Sonderweg'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonderweg) had on the [Revolution of 1848 in Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_revolutions_of_1848%E2%80%9349).  Are there authoritative/canonical references that would help?
PS: Since I also speak German and Spanish, any article/book in English, German or Spanish is also accepted ;)

Comment: Questions for this forum must be phrased and framed in such a way as to allow for a definitive answer. This question neither meets this standard, not appears to have even been intended to. Please read the [faq](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) on how to ask a question.

Comment: Could you rephrase that from a request for literature to an actual problem? (Guessing that you read Wikipedia and Wehler/Winkler…) Try to demonstrate your prior research and what problems arise from that for you. Something like "How/why can the revolution of 1848 be interpreted as the start/part of the *Sonderweg*, given that [I found the following conflicting (info/discrepancies/bad explanation)  in XY]?

Comment: I've made what I hope is a friendly edit.  @Drmathva, could you validate?  Is this sufficient for reopen?  Or would you like to revise further?  The question is still rather broad, but I hope that I've focused it to a question, rather than a request for discussion/sources.

Comment: The question doesn't ask about the effect of the 1848 revolution on the Sonderweg, as LangLang's version does - and I agree that such a question would be very broad. The question is the opposite, that is, whether the 1848 revolution has been seen as an effect of Sonderweg. I don't see as too broad an answer summarising if 1848 revolution in Germany has been seen as very different from 1848 revolution in other places and whether such differences are claimed to be attributed to the same Sonderweg that allegedly leaded to Nazism.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Thanks for the edit, it's perfect!

Comment: And @Pere, you're totally right!

Comment: @Dr.Mathva: It's in the queue for consideration, with now 3, of 5 needed, votes to reopen recorded. I believe there is a strong chance it will be reopened sometime this morning. Our *diamond* moderators generally use a light touch, allowing the community to adjudicate most such questions, which has worked well for us.

Comment: I'd like to re-open this, but it is very broad and still lacks your prior attempts at this. What have you read about this? (I named 2 authors and the WPs for en, es , de list quite some more). Another point that would help convince *me* would be to add a *little* more of your current understanding of your question's content or objective. (& perhaps: what does *Sonderweg* mean to you? [which school of thought is your starting point?])

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mishear a remark about the effect of the Sonderbundskrieg on the Revolutuion of 1848?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend these articles:
http://oxfordindex.oup.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199249978.003.0006
https://www.jstor.org/stable/40108749?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents
https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/hf/iakh/HIS2351/h11/undervisningsmateriale/HIS2351_Kocka_HistoryBefore%20Hitler.pdf

Comment: Link-only answers are generally frowned upon on SE.  While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference. This way our answer would remain valid even in case of [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)